# Usage of session to retain to text box value in PHP

Tags: php

Hi I have this and works fine except the following issue.

```
  echo "<form method='post' action=''>";
  echo "  <input type='text' name='txt1' id='txt1' value=".$_SESSION['txt1'].">";
  echo "  <input type='submit' name='sendtwo' id='sendtwo' value='TwoClick'>";
  echo "</form>";
<A submit button here to send the form data>
```

The issue is if I have a value in the text box like `John` when I submit the form I retain the original user typed word `Jonn` in the text box. However if the user type `John Carter`, when the form is submitted it retains only `John`. In other words texts only up to first space between the texts. How do I retain entire text?

**EDIT**

```
<?php
  if(isset($_POST['sendone']))
  {
    echo "Hello";
    echo "<form method='post' action=''>";
    echo "  <input type='text' name='txt1' id='txt1'>";
    echo "  <input type='submit' name='sendtwo' id='sendtwo' value='TwoClick'>";
    echo "</form>";
  }
  if(isset($_POST['sendtwo']))
  {
    if($_POST['txt1']=='')
    {
      echo "Hello";
      echo "<form method='post' action=''>";
      echo "  <input type='text' name='txt1' id='txt1'>";
      echo "  <input type='submit' name='sendtwo' id='sendtwo' value='TwoClick'>";
      echo "</form>";
      echo "Empty";
    }
    else
    {
      $_SESSION['txt1'] = $_POST['txt1'];
      echo "Hello";
      echo "<form method='post' action=''>";
      echo "  <input type='text' name='txt1' id='txt1' value=".$_SESSION['txt1'].">";
      echo "  <input type='submit' name='sendtwo' id='sendtwo' value='TwoClick'>";
      echo "</form>";
      echo "Hit success!";      
    }
  }
  ?>
```

Comment: Can you show us PHP code how you are storing in session?

Comment: @Atul I have edited my question and you'll see the full code

Comment: What is sendone and sendtwo do you have nested forms??

Comment: @Atul Yes. Sorry for not making it clear. Sendone is the submit button in form 1 which activates the form 2. Form 2 content you see above.

Comment: You can not have nested forms in HTML

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/379610/can-you-nest-html-forms

Comment: @Atul this is not a situation I have form2 inside form 1 or vise visa. Two seperate forms and form 1 calls form 2 to be visible. Please see some comment I made for the below answer by Mr. alien

Comment: AAh ok.. I think problem is you have both the text boxees with same name... Can you change the name of one text box and try??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include the single quotes around the value for the `value=` attribue when `echo`ing the `_SESSION["txt1"]`, otherwise the resulting HTML isn't valid .. like this:

```
<?php
  if(isset($_POST['sendone']))
  {
    echo "Hello";
    echo "<form method='post' action=''>";
    echo "  <input type='text' name='txt1' id='txt1'>";
    echo "  <input type='submit' name='sendtwo' id='sendtwo' value='TwoClick'>";
    echo "</form>";
  }
  if(isset($_POST['sendtwo']))
  {
    if($_POST['txt1']=='')
    {
      echo "Hello";
      echo "<form method='post' action=''>";
      echo "  <input type='text' name='txt1' id='txt1'>";
      echo "  <input type='submit' name='sendtwo' id='sendtwo' value='TwoClick'>";
      echo "</form>";
      echo "Empty";
    }
    else
    {
      $_SESSION['txt1'] = $_POST['txt1'];
      echo "Hello";
      echo "<form method='post' action=''>";

      // check out this line here:
      echo "  <input type='text' name='txt1' id='txt1' value='" . htmlspecialchars($_SESSION['txt1']) . "'>";

      echo "  <input type='submit' name='sendtwo' id='sendtwo' value='TwoClick'>";
      echo "</form>";
      echo "Hit success!";      
    }
  }
?>
```

Though, it's worth nothing that it is much more performant (and readable!) to use plain HTML where possible, and just use `echo` for the variables you wish to include.

Comment: You also need to escape the output using `htmlspecialchars()`

Answer (score 0):

Check this code.

```
<form name="" method="post">
<input type="text" name="txt1">
<input type="submit" name="sendtwo">
<input type="submit" name="sendone">
</form>

<?php
  if(isset($_POST['sendone']))
  {
    echo "Hello";
    echo "<form method='post' action=''>";
    echo "  <input type='text' name='txt1' id='txt1'>";
    echo "  <input type='submit' name='sendtwo' id='sendtwo' value='TwoClick'>";
    echo "</form>";
  }
  if(isset($_POST['sendtwo']))
  {
    if($_POST['txt1']=='')
    {
      echo "Hello";
      echo "<form method='post' action=''>";
      echo "  <input type='text' name='txt1' id='txt1'>";
      echo "  <input type='submit' name='sendtwo' id='sendtwo' value='TwoClick'>";
      echo "</form>";
      echo "Empty";
    }
    else
    {
      $_SESSION['txt1'] = $_POST['txt1'];
      echo "Hello";
      echo "<form method='post' action=''>";

      // check out this line here:
      echo "  <input type='text' name='txt1' id='txt1' value='" . $_SESSION['txt1'] . "'>";

      echo "  <input type='submit' name='sendtwo' id='sendtwo' value='TwoClick'>";
      echo "</form>";
      echo "Hit success!";      
    }
  }
?>
```

Comment: can you post the code from which the values are generated for sendone and sendtwo

Comment: Assume form one has only a submit button. The form 2 content is in my question under edit. Thank you for looking.

Comment: you are using sendtwo and sendone ie there have to be two submit buttons in form one..

Comment: I have updated the code, please check if it works for you. I assume you have 2 submit buttons in form one. `<input type="submit" name="sendtwo">
<input type="submit" name="sendone">`